# How to avoid re-write style, Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I use react js

I usually face problem like this

```
<div style={display: 'flex'}>
   <div>Content 1</div>
   <div>Content 2</div>
   <div>Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Let's assume above element had styled finished.

Then start to make rwd style

The problem is here.

I usually found that I need added new element to wrap it because I need to make rwd style.

Like this

```
<div style={display: 'flex'}>
   <div>  // add this element
       <div>Content 1</div>
       <div>Content 2</div>
   </div>
   <div>Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Then, I need to change style that I had finished, because I added new element.

Do any better way to avoid that?

Comment: why don't you use CSS framework? and flexbox should work without an extra `div` here.

Comment: Content1 and Content2 need to stack and content3 is beside to 1 and 2,  could flexbox choose some item to stack and some item no stack?

Comment: For anything other than a simple container, styling everything with inline CSS can be hugely challenging and perhaps counter-productive. You might want to consider using `styled-component` (or other `CSS-in-JS` approaches), or a CSS Modules approach. They'll give you more flexibility with DOM markup changes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use a tag selector such as div to select all the divs in your document or component in react context. While it is not the best way to handle it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).